# Code won't give desired output or read second input

Tags: c#

Sorry if this isn't the right. This is my first time posting here. I'm a first year Software student and for the life of me i cannot seem to get this to work. I know its something simple I'm missing but oh well. I tried doing this using methods but again no help. Maybe you guys could help me?

The problem is the code wont let me input after the "Are you a member (Y/N)" writline statement and just keeps giving me an output of 50.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Local Variable Declaration//

    double rate1 = 10;
    double rate2 = 3;
    double maxCharge = 50;
    double charge;

    Console.WriteLine("Enter number of hours (-999 to quit) : ");
    int hoursRented = Console.Read();

    if (hoursRented >= 3)
    {
        charge = hoursRented * rate1;
    }
    else
    {
        charge = (3 * rate1) + (hoursRented * rate2);
    }

    if (charge > maxCharge)
    {
        charge = maxCharge;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Are you a member? (Y/N) : ");
    int memberStatus = Console.Read();

    if (memberStatus.Equals("Y"))
    {
        charge = (charge * 1 / 10) - charge;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Customer Charge : {0}   Total Charge To Date :  ", charge);            
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `Console.ReadLine` instead so that pressing enter will indicate the end of the input from the user.  Also `Console.Read` returns the Ascii code of the next character entered, not the numeric value.

Comment: change `int memberStatus = Console.Read();` to `string memberStatus = Console.ReadLine();`

Comment: Note you also need to change `int hoursRented = Console.Read();` to something like `int hoursRented = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());`, thought I'd suggest using `int.TryParse` instead to check for invalid input.

Comment: You might want to read over the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) so you'll know what everything does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problematic lines are below

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter number of hours (-999 to quit) : ");
int hoursRented = Console.Read();
if (hoursRented >= 3) {
```

and

```
Console.WriteLine("Are you a member? (Y/N) : ");
int memberStatus = Console.Read();
if (memberStatus.Equals("Y")) {
```

When you call [`Console.Read()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read(v=vs.110).aspx), it reads only characters and returns it as an int. You seem to **mistakenly** think it will parse the character to an `int`.

Secondly, think what happens when you provide multiple characters as input to a single `Console.Read()` call. Interestingly, the remaining characters are read in the subsequent calls. So when you type any number followed by `Enter` in the first `Console.Read` it only, reads the first character, the subsequent characters, including the EOLN char are returned in the subsequent calls, instead of prompting you to enter information for the next call.

The fix is easy. Use `Console.Readline()` and `int.parse` (or its `int.TryParse()` variant

Then the corresponding code will look like below

```
Console.Write("Enter number of hours (-999 to quit) : ");
string hoursRentedStr = Console.ReadLine();
int hoursRented = int.Parse(hoursRentedStr);

if (hoursRented >= 3) {
```

and

```
Console.Write("Are you a member? (Y/N) : ");
string memberStatus = Console.ReadLine();

if (memberStatus.Equals("Y")) {
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are just writing:

```
Console.WriteLine("Are you a member? (Y/N) : ");
```

and continuing through.

you must do it like this:

```
 Console.WriteLine("Are you a member? (Y/N) : ");
 Console.ReadLine();
```

and then:

```
int memberStatus = Int.Parse(Console.ReadKey());
```

Comment: `Console.ReadKey` does not return `int`.

Comment: Then he should parse it using TryParse. No console object will return and int, as far as I know.

Comment: It doesn't return `string` either.  It returns `ConsoleKeyInfo`, and `Console.Read` does return an `int`, it's just that it's the Ascci code for a character.

Comment: Thanks guys. I knew it was something i was just overlooking. Astounded by the response time but its all fixed now. It was the Console.Read() should have been Console.Readline() then convert to int. Tanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that your are using Console.Read wich returns the ascii code of the next charachter as said by @juharr in the comments. so the solution is too simply replace Read By ReadLine and change your code like this, so that ReadLine wich is a string will be converted to the int value that you want

```
int hoursRented = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

And change your member status to a string to compare it with "Y" easily

```
string memberStatus = Console.ReadLine();
```

Note: if you want to validate the input you should use a `int.TryParse` instead of just a normal parse like I used as it returns a bool so you knows when it fails